# Add the DLL (lame_enc.dll) reference to my project

Tags: vb.net

I need to convert all types of audio formats to the mp3.
I think I need to add the refrence of the dll (lame_enc.dll) into my .net application.

When I try to add the DLL reference to my project, I get an **error: "A reference to C:\Lame_Enc.dll could not be added. Please make sure this file is accessible and that it is a valid assembly or COM component"**

Is there any other solution that I can convert all types of audio formats to the mp3 and also I need to convert all types of video formats to the flv.

Many thanks for your consideration.

Answer (score 1):

Why reinvent the wheel? Here

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/audio-video/MP3Compressor.aspx

you find a .NET wrapper library for lame_enc.dll. It is written in C#, but usage from VB.NET should be no problem.

By the way, if you want to use native DLLs (no COM, no .NET) from a VB.NET program, you don't have to add a reference to that DLL, you just have to copy that DLL into your working directory of your VB.NET program and use PInvoke. Read this tutorial (C# only, sorry)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288468%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

to learn more about it.

Comment: the reason that i am following to add this dll to my project is because I think this dll helps to convert all audio formats to each other an also all video formats to one another.

Comment: To use the lame_enc dll to convert audio and video files in vb.net I imported the System.Runtime.InteropServices in the converetor class, after that I inserted the <DllImport("Lame_enc.dll", SetLastError:=True, CharSet:=CharSet.Auto)> above my share function. Now ,what kind of attributes I should use in the share function to access the functions and classes and subroutines in the lame_ens.dll. please help with thanks