# Inject the .DLL from project

Tags: vb.net, dll, exe

I need to inject the `.dll` to specified `.exe` in my project.

```
Private Sub Timer2_Tick(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer2.Tick
    'If IsProcessRunning("Chrome") = True Then

    'End If
```

**Picture**

[image]

Any helps?  I already have injector codes which is `LoadLibraryA`.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot inject a .net assembly using the `CreateRemoteThread`, `LoadLibrary` technique. Remember that `LoadLibrary` loads unmanaged libraries rather than managed assemblies.

You should re-write your code in an unmanaged language, and inject the resulting unmanaged DLL.

Comment: Thanks, now i did a console injector which injects that .dll and added the both to solution explorer. What should i do make it start in solution explorer ? I imported System.Diagnostics.Process in my code btw. I can't find the sol. explorer's path tho..

Comment: I don't understand that. It sounds like you are still trying to inject a managed assembly with LoadLibrary.

Comment: No. I said i created a CreateRemoteThread injector that injects HS.dll. I mean, i want to start that CRT .exe injector that i added into sol. explorer. Not the HS.dll. Isn't it possible with that way ? o:

Comment: I can't really understand this. I don't what these names refer to. I think my answer addresses the question that you asked.

Comment: Look at that image. I want to make HS_Injector.exe start with a timer. : http://i61.tinypic.com/2vb56ci.png

Comment: I suggest that you edit the question so that it is clear what you are asking. It was my belief that you wanted to inject a managed assembly into another process. Was I wrong?

Comment: I firstly asked it, then you said it's not possible with your first comment. Then i'm asking for alternative ways. What's the problem ?

Comment: Well, that's not really how it works here. You ask specific questions and we try to answer. We don't work through an entire problem with you. Perhaps you need a new question asking how to solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean you have to use the methods in the dll file? Then you have to add the DLL file to your project reference.

Please click [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17275804/2977532) to refer to the answer.

Comment: A reference to the "....dll" could not be added.Please make sure that the file is accessible and that it is a valid assembly or COM component. ._.